# AttributeError: 'AppConfig' object has no attribute 'urls'

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

**Issue Summary**

Installed django-oscar sandbox app successfully but getting a small error in django-oscar/sandbox/urls.py at the line url(r'^', include(apps.get_app_config('oscar').urls[0])),

**Error Message:**

> AttributeError: 'AppConfig' object has no attribute 'urls'

The 'apps' above is comming from django package:
`from django.apps import apps`
and using it in

`url(r'^', include(apps.get_app_config('oscar').urls[0])),`

I googled it but didn't find the solution. I am following the instuructions available on your official django-oscar website: https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/internals/sandbox.html to make the sandbox app up and running locally.

**Technical details**

- Python version: 3.5.2
- Django version:2.1.7
- Oscar version: 1.6.7(django-oscar)

Comment: Is this a copy/paste of [this github issue](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/issues/2958)?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, it looks like it is...

Comment: yes bro I posted on github as well to get the correct answer soon.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that this was the right thing to do? It's not what the docs you link to say at all.

Comment: You are trying to us the sandbox from github master with Oscar 1.6 - this will not work. You need to use the sandbox from the 1.6 release branch. I'm not too sure how you've managed to use the 1.6 sandbox with master of Oscar.